# all table, constraint,... i have deleted still exist in new connection ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

all table, constraint,... i have deleted still exist in new connection ORACLE
** is there any solution to delete schema in oracle**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to drop your schema?
Then use

```
DROP SCHEMA schemaName RESTRICT;
```

If you can delete the user then all associated object/schema will be deleted.

```
DROP USER username CASCADE;
```

Comment: i tried but it not work. i use sql developer and right click then choose delete then create new connection ,all table, trigger,.. off deleted schema exist in new schema

Comment: What exactly did you right-click on and delete? The schema/user, individual objects, or the connection?